# Difference between result_array() and result() in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have in my model these two function:

```
function get_products($product_id = FALSE)
        {
                if ($product_id === FALSE)
                {
                        $query = $this->db->get('products');
                        return $query->result_array();
                }

                $query = $this->db->get_where('products', array('product_id' => $product_id));
                return $query->row_array();
        }
function get_coordinates()
        {
            $return = array();
            $this->db->select("latitude,longitude, user_id");
            $this->db->from("user_profiles");
            $query = $this->db->get();
            if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            array_push($return, $row);
            }
            }
            return $return;
        }
```

and these two methods in my controller:

```
function index()
        {
                $data['products'] = $this->products_model->get_products();

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('products/index', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
public function map()
        {
                ...

                $coords = $this->products_model->get_coordinates();

                // Loop through the coordinates we obtained above and add them to the map
                foreach ($coords as $coordinate) {
                $marker = array();
                $marker['position'] = $coordinate->latitude.','.$coordinate->longitude;
                $marker['infowindow_content'] = $coordinate->user_id;

                $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
                }
                // Create the map
                $data = array();
                $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
                // Load our view, passing through the map
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('maps_view', $data);

        }
```

Website core idea is that users can add products and products will be displayed on map with information in infowindow.
Originally I created get_coordinates because lat/lng values are stored in user_profiles table. Working with CodeIgniter Google Maps V3 API Library I found it hard to display information in infowindow from different table so I adjusted set_products and lat/lng now are being taken from user_profiles table and stored in products table as well.

I thought that I could use `$coords = $this->products_model->get_coordinates();` in my map method but I get error: `Trying to get property of non-object` on `$marker['position'] = $coordinate->latitude.','.$coordinate->longitude;` line.

From what I see there is difference in return type for `get_coordinates` and `get_products`. I read CodeIgniters user guide on [Generating query results](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) but still feel confused.

Of course I could adjust get_coordinates by changing table name(which works) but then I have to functions that are doing besically the same. I would love if I could just use get_puzzles but in order for me to make neccessary changes I need to understand the difference.

So if some one please could describe differences between result_array() and result() in CodeIgniter I would be happy man.

Comment: There is no error in the provided code. The snippet is not refined or optimal, but it is not broken either.  **Off-topic: Cannot Reproduce**

Answer (score 2):

Difference between result_array() and result() :

result_array() returns output in array of array format  but 
result() returns output in array of object format

For result_array() you need to use :

```
foreach($datas as $row) {
   $name = $row['name'];
}
```

for result() you can use :

```
foreach($datas as $row) {
   $name = $row->name;
}
```

Comment: I made the change `$marker['position'] = $coordinate['latitude.']','.$coordinate['longitude'];` and now I get error: `Message: syntax error, unexpected '','' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)` I realy do not get two different syntaxes for same result. Could you pleast help with error and suggest keywords to look-up for better understanding?

Comment: You need to cancat the ',' with $coordinate['latitude']. You are missing a '.' There..

Comment: use this $marker['position'] = $coordinate['latitude'].','.$coordinate['longitude'];

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly Rijin's answer worded differently.

Difference between `result_array()` and `result()` :

`result_array()` returns an array of arrays. 
`result()` returns an array of objects.

I don't see anything wrong with the code as presented in the question. The error message indicates that `$coordinate` is not an object. But, if the model code shown is accurate, it should be an object.

`get_coordinates()` could be a lot simpler. The whole `foreach` loop is completely pointless because it simply recreates the same data structure that `$query->result()` returns. Try this code

```
public function get_coordinates()
{
    $this->db->select("latitude, longitude, user_id");
    $query = $this->db->get("user_profiles");
    return $query->num_rows() > 0 ?  $query->result() : array();
}
```

If you continue to get the `Trying to get property of non-object` error try putting

```
var_dump($coords);
return;
```

before the `foreach` loop in your controller. It might be helpful to see exactly what the loop is trying to use.

Comment: Simpler again, `result()` unconditionally generates an array -- it will either produce an empty array or an array of objects.  The `num_rows()` condition is needless.  I would do `public function get_coordinates(): array
{
    return $this->db->select("latitude, longitude, user_id")->get("user_profiles")->result();
}`. I find this question to be **Off-Topic: Cannot Reproduce**.